# How to define cache control for AWSS3TransferUtility

Tags: ios, caching, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios

I'm struggling to define cache control when uploading images via the `AWSS3TransferUtility` (AWS-iOS-SDK v2.4.x).

My simplified usage is like:

```
let utility = AWSS3TransferUtility.S3TransferUtilityForKey("key")
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)!

let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
expression.progressBlock = { (task, progress) in
    onProgress?(progress: progress.fractionCompleted)
}

transferUtility.uploadData(data, bucket: GlobalConfig.awsS3DefaultBucket, key: "image.jpeg", contentType: "image/jpeg", expression: expression) { (task, error) in
    // ...
}
```

My current focus was on the expression, but calls like `expression.setValue("max-age=3600", forRequestParameter: "Cache-Control")` didn't work.

Comment: using `expression.setValue("max-age=3600", forRequestParameter: "Cache-Control")` should work. Try downloading the content and see if you get the cache-control header in the response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I wrote, it is not working. Neither `curl` nor directly checking the bucket shows any additional headers. However, I can manually add headers in S3 and get them via `curl` :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use *forRequestParameter* use *forRequestHeader*

example:

```
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
expression.setValue("max-age=3600", forRequestHeader: "Cache-Control")
```

Comment: I'm not working on that project anymore, but now with some distance it looks quite obvious to use the request *header* instead of the parameter.